# Materialize CSS - in mobile collapse menu, links with icons are not vertically centered

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, materialize

Maybe it's a bug, I'm not sure, but when using the mobile collapse menu, the icons and the text are not aligned (see images).

The reason is because of these CSS properties:

HTML:

```css
.side-nav a {
    color: #444;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1rem;
    height: 64px;
    line-height: 64px;
    padding: 0 30px;
}

nav i.material-icons {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  height: 56px;
  line-height: 56px;
}
```

```html
<ul style="transform: translateX(0px);" class="side-nav" id="mobile-menu">
  <img src="images/costum_logos/logo3.png" class="custom-logo">
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <a href="index.php" class="waves-effect waves-light">Albums
    <i class="material-icons left notranslate">collections</i>
  </a>
  <a href="?page=settings" class="waves-effect waves-light">Settings
    <i class="material-icons left notranslate">settings</i></a>
  <a class="waves-effect waves-light red-text text-lighten-1" href="index.php?logout">Logout
    <i class="material-icons left notranslate">power_settings_new</i>
  </a>
</ul>
```

Of course, the interesting bits are the `line-height` and `height` properties on both the anchor tag, and the icon tag. They are not equal. If I override either one of them, to be exactly like the other - they are perfectly aligned.

[image: Icon and text are not vertically aligned]

[image: Icon and text are vertically aligned after changing the icon's height and line-height to 64px]

My question is: Am I doing something wrong? I can easily get around it, but  I want to have a good practice with materialize CSS. Don't wanna hack around and break their conventions.

Thanks in advance!